# What do curly braces after a struct variable member mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

During some maintenance (Valgrind'ing) I came across this code:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct somename
{
  uint16_t a{};
  uint16_t b{};
  uint32_t  c{};
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I would expect that the `{}` tell the compiler to always initialize the values to 0 (when allocating using new, or using a stack variable), but I cannot find any examples or documentation on that. Am I correct in this assumption? If not:

What do the curly braces `{}` after a struct member variable mean?

Comment: [data_members#Member_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11).

(emphasis mine)

> Through a default member initializer, **which is a brace or equals initializer included in the member declaration** and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.
>
> If a member has a default member initializer and also appears in the member initialization list in a constructor, the default member initializer is ignored for that constructor.

As the effect, the data members `a`, `b` and `c` are [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) ([zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) for built-in types) to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

It is zero initialization as documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) (second case):

So all values are set to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization):

> Value initialization is performed when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) is declared with the initializer consisting of a pair of braces `T{}`.

The effect of value initialization is that the object is zero-initialized.